# How do I change Code styling for a file with PHP, JS, and HTML in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

When I create a new html file in PHPstorm and type `<div class="test">` it will auto complete the HTML DOM tag `</div>`. If I click enter it will automatically move the `</div>` tag to the proper indention.

However, I have a file that has PHP, JS, and HTML all in one. It is not ideal but it is legacy code that would take awhile to rewrite. When I type `<div class="test">` it does not auto complete the closing tag. Then I click enter and type out the closing `</div>` tag. The closing tag is now indented like it is a child of the opening tag and I have to remove those spaces.

Not a huge deal, but pretty annoying since all my files work this way for some reason.

I believe the answer lies somewhere in telling the file which code style/code highlighting it should be using but I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **`Settings`**(**ctrl+alt+s**)

**`Editor-> General -> Smart Key`** Tick all these options

[image]

> And in **`Editor-> General -> Code Style`** and go to `other` then there is some options about indent. With the preview you can identify what is changing.